# PHP OpenSSL extension missing error after upgrade

Tags: php

In a WAMP64 environment, I have upgraded PHP from 5.6.25 to 7.4.28. I also upgraded PHPMailer to the latest and greatest.
Now when I try to use PHPmail I get the openssl extension missing.
If I back down to PHP version 7.0.10 or back to 5.6.25....there are no issues.
OpenSSL is there and when I try to just run the executable, I get SSLEAV32.dll and LIBEAV32.dll are not found.
PHPINFO() does not show SSL loaded.
So I am thinking I missed an upgrade on something.
Any ideas?

Comment: You've not said anything about how you installed PHP, though we can guess it's on Windows, and you need to also install the OpenSSL PHP extension too.

Comment: Initial PHP was installed as part of the WAMP64 install process. Yes on Windows for this one. I updated PHP from Wampserver website. I read in the Wamp docs that openSSL comes with it and it works with PHP 5.6.25.

Comment: I just toggled back to PHP version 5.6.25 and ran the code to check for the extension...and it is loaded on 5.6.25. It shows loaded for version 7.0.10. When I change to version 7.4.28, openSSL is not loaded.

Comment: I did a full removal and reinstalled Wamp64. This took care of the problem. So assuming some piece of the puzzle in the upgrade process did not get copied in or installed correctly. PHPMailer is working as expected now.